# formatting unstructured array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I currently have a flat dataset that i'd like to format differently with header names. I've tried searching up examples for something similar but i've not been able to find anything. I only need the first 3 items in the first array before creating a second one with the second set of data. The data i have is:

```
[
['Peoples Revolutionary Party',
    '52',
    '#F2D7D5',
    'Peoples Revolutionary Party',
    'Farmer Labor Party',
    '40',
    '#1db309',
    'Farmer Labor Party',
    'Democratic Party',
    '145',
    '#1c7eff',
    'Democratic Party',
    'NEW',
    '1',
    '#ff0000',
    'NEW',
    'States Rights Party',
    '5',
    '#011d57',
    'States Rights Party',
    'The Party',
    '58',
    '#800020',
    'The Party',
    'California National Party',
    '9',
    '#d9a517',
    'California National Party',
    'Independent',
    '7',
    'grey',
    'Independent',
    'United Foxboro Party',
    '2',
    '#0722ed',
    'United Foxboro Party',
    'Republican Party',
    '75',
    'red',
    'Republican Party',
    'Gulf Coast Party',
    '16',
    '#b4b710',
    'Gulf Coast Party',
    'Libertarian Party',
    '11',
    '#ffd700',
    'Libertarian Party',
    'American Fascist Party',
    '8',
    '#000000',
    'American Fascist Party',
    'American Nationalist Party',
    '2',
    '#5c4033',
    'American Nationalist Party']
]
```

I'd like to get the data like this:

```
[
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}],
[name: "Peoples Revolutionary Party", info: {seats: "52", color: "#F2D7D5"}]
]
```

Comment: you'll need to slice it 4 at a time and then convert those four elements into the object you want - why is it a two dimensinal array though? - also, your output is invalid format

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: @Tune, https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: by using array slice and other code

Comment: `const output = input.map(a => a.slice(0,a.length>>2).map((_,i)=>({name:a[i<<2],info:{seats:a[(i<<2)+1],color:a[(i<<2)+2]}})));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that ?

```js
const input = ['Peoples Revolutionary Party',
    '52',
    '#F2D7D5',
    'Peoples Revolutionary Party',
    'Farmer Labor Party',
    '40',
    '#1db309',
    'Farmer Labor Party',
    'Democratic Party',
    '145',
    '#1c7eff',
    'Democratic Party',
    'NEW',
    '1',
    '#ff0000',
    'NEW',
    'States Rights Party',
    '5',
    '#011d57',
    'States Rights Party',
    'The Party',
    '58',
    '#800020',
    'The Party',
    'California National Party',
    '9',
    '#d9a517',
    'California National Party',
    'Independent',
    '7',
    'grey',
    'Independent',
    'United Foxboro Party',
    '2',
    '#0722ed',
    'United Foxboro Party',
    'Republican Party',
    '75',
    'red',
    'Republican Party',
    'Gulf Coast Party',
    '16',
    '#b4b710',
    'Gulf Coast Party',
    'Libertarian Party',
    '11',
    '#ffd700',
    'Libertarian Party',
    'American Fascist Party',
    '8',
    '#000000',
    'American Fascist Party',
    'American Nationalist Party',
    '2',
    '#5c4033',
    'American Nationalist Party'];


let i,j,chunk = 4
const output = [];

for ( i=0, j=input.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
  
    let part = input.slice(i,i+chunk);
  
  output.push({
    name: part[0],
    info: {
      color: part[2],
      seats: part[1]
    }
  });
  
  
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: close, but you've changed the OP's input data  to a single dimensional array

Comment: His output makes no sense, `[name: xxx, info: {...}]` is not valid

Comment: If you use `const [name, color, seats] = input.slice(i, i + chunk)` you can change you push call to `output.push({ name, info: { color, seats } });` which is cleaner imo.